# .forEach(...) is undefined while fetching

Tags: javascript, foreach, fetch

I want to print every object of a JSON object by using the fetch API and iterate the response with a forEach method
    function

```
 artistSelected(evt){
        let artistId = evt.target.parentElement.id;  
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/artists/"+artistId+"/albums")
            .then((response) => {  
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                } else {
                    throw new Error('a problem occured');
                }
            })
            .then((response) => {    
                let albums = response;
                albums.forEach(value => {
                    console.log(value) 
                })
            .catch((error) => { 
                console.log(error);
            })
        })
    }
```

when I run the function, I have the error `TypeError: albums.forEach(...) is undefined` and I cannot print every objects

an example of the Album JSON response could be:

```
[
  {
    "id": "the_rolling_stones",
    "artistId": "rolling_stones",
    "year": 1964,
    "title": "The Rolling Stones",
    "label": "ABKCO Records",
    "cover": "http://cps-static.rovicorp.com/3/JPG_500/MI0002/193/MI0002193977.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "12_5",
    "year": 1964,
    "artistId": "rolling_stones",
    "title": "12x5",
    "label": "ABKCO Records",
    "cover": "http://cps-static.rovicorp.com/3/JPG_500/MI0000/498/MI0000498502.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "out_of_our_heads",
    "artistId": "rolling_stones",
    "year": 1965,
    "title": "Out of Our Heads",
    "label": "ABKCO Records",
    "cover": "http://cps-static.rovicorp.com/3/JPG_500/MI0001/682/MI0001682084.jpg"
  }
]
```

and when I print the response of the first '.then' I have:

Res

```
ponse { type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:3000/artists/the_clash/albums", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }
```

Comment: how does `albums` look like

Comment: Log `albums` to the console and check the data and its type. Please post the exact error. *"forEach(...) is undefined"* seems unlikely. It should either be "*Cannot read property `forEach` of undefined*" or *"`forEach` is not a function*"

Comment: It's likely that `response` is not an array. Double check this by `console.log(response)` in each part.

Comment: The response is an array however, when I print I have Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: my error is just TypeError: albums.forEach(...) is undefined

Comment: The response object is not an array, it's an object containing multiple properties.

Comment: Can you add the output of `response.json()`?

Comment: it is, I print it and it says it's an array: Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]

Comment: Put this line: `console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(albums));` after the declaration of `albums`, what do you see?

Comment: I have [object Array]

Comment: Is this not actually just a typesafety issue? because the 2nd response has the possibility to be undefined? i.e. resulting in the `TypeError: albums.forEach(...) is undefined` ? It's not saying albums is undefined, it's saying the `.forEach` is undefined.

Comment: If that really logs `[object Array]`, then either the error is coming from somewhere else, or somebody has monkeypatched Array prototype, and removed `forEach` method.

Answer (score 0):

#### Assuming it's a typesafety issue, the solution is as follows:

```js
.then((response) => {
  if (response) {
    let albums = response.json();
    albums.forEach(value => {
      console.log(value)
    })
  } else {
    throw new Error('a problem occured');
  }
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
})
```

Comment: They pass `response.json()` from the previous promise handler, and the typecheck seems to show that `albums` really is an array. Hence I think you've to check `response` instead of `response.ok`, since there's no `ok` property in the data.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, 
I don't know why nobody saw it but the catch wasn't in the right place, because when I switch to Chrome, the error is not from the foreach but from the catch.

Answer (score -3):

For a reference, I am taking your JSON response(Array of objects) and by that, we can easily iterate the array by foreach loop

```js
var album =[
  {
    "id": "the_rolling_stones",
    "artistId": "rolling_stones",
    "year": 1964,
    "title": "The Rolling Stones",
    "label": "ABKCO Records",
    "cover": "http://cps-static.rovicorp.com/3/JPG_500/MI0002/193/MI0002193977.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "12_5",
    "year": 1964,
    "artistId": "rolling_stones",
    "title": "12x5",
    "label": "ABKCO Records",
    "cover": "http://cps-static.rovicorp.com/3/JPG_500/MI0000/498/MI0000498502.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "out_of_our_heads",
    "artistId": "rolling_stones",
    "year": 1965,
    "title": "Out of Our Heads",
    "label": "ABKCO Records",
    "cover": "http://cps-static.rovicorp.com/3/JPG_500/MI0001/682/MI0001682084.jpg"
  }
];
album.forEach(value =>{
 console.log(value.title)
});
```

Comment: How does this solve OP's issue? OP already knows about the forEach method. If the question doesn't have enough details, it should be closed not answered.